# counting words in a datacolumn in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

hi  I have a dataframe,

df,

```
 Name
 Raj
 NaN
 Ravi,kumar
```

I am trying to get the count of words in df["Name"],

I tried, `df['count']=df['Names'].str.count(',') + 1`

but I am getting "1" for NaN field, how to resolve this
I am getting

```
 Name        count
 Raj          1
 NaN          1  
 Ravi,kumar   2
```

but my desired output should be,

```
 Name        count
 Raj          1
 NaN            
 Ravi,kumar   2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `NaN` is a string here. Try doing this:

```
df['Name'].replace('NaN', np.nan).str.count(',') + 1
```

You should get something along these lines:

```
0    1.0
1    NaN
2    2.0
Name: Name, dtype: float64
```

You can then call `.fillna('')` to fill in the blanks.

Comment: I am getting `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'replace'`

Comment: @CHANDRAMURUGAN OK. Use the `['...']` bracket notation then.

Comment: ya tried that too but getting 1 for all the NaN fields

Comment: @CHANDRAMURUGAN What does `df['Name'].isnull().sum()` display?

Comment: @CHANDRAMURUGAN, it could also be a version issue. This works for me on 0.21. Try upgrading - `pip install --upgrade pandas`.

Comment: how to check my pandas version

Comment: @CHANDRAMURUGAN `print(pd.__version__)`

Comment: your last edited code is working fine, why are you givving `{}` braces

Comment: @CHANDRAMURUGAN my bad, was a typo.

Comment: @CHANDRAMURUGAN It needs to be a dictionary: `{'NaN' : np.nan}`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need np.where i.e

```
df['count'] = np.where(df['Name']!='NaN',df['Name'].str.count(',')+1,'')

         Name count
0         Raj   1.0
1         NaN      
2  Ravi,kumar   2.0
```

Comment: Actually, surprisingly, OP's solution of counting commas here is pretty performant.

Comment: Okay, I had 2 votes left, spent one on this. 1 more left now.

Comment: @Bharath still it is giving 1 for all NaN fields

Comment: I wonder how your actual data looks like. Is that a floating Nan or String Nan